# Mysql (5.1.41) dynamic SQL in stored procedure issue

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that populates a temp table. The temp table is populated using multiple dynamic SQL (it has "having" & "between" clause). I am executing this SQL inside my stored procedure using:

```
set @sql = concat("insert into my_temp select * from my_table where my_date between ", date1, " and ", date2)
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

/* more prepared dynamic statements */
```

The problem is my driver complaints as soon as it encounters the first EXECUTE statement, apparently it thinks MySQL is trying to return a resultset from a stored procedure. Is that how mysql behaves when it comes to dynamic sqls in stored procedures?

I get this error from ruby/rails/mysql2 driver -

```
Mysql2::Error: PROCEDURE my_db.sp_special_customers can't return a result set in the given context:
```

Basically the driver does not support returning result-sets from stored procedure, which is fine. And that's not the issue, the issue for me is why does my driver think that EXECUTE stmt1 means a result set is being returned?

Is there a way in Mysql to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html

Particularly: "Stored routines cannot contain arbitrary SQL statements. The following statements are not permitted: "

They don't allow 'EXECUTE' in the stored procedure. You can however use prepared statements if you're using mysql 5.x. It might be a viable alternative, depending on what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: i m on 5.1.x, so i am good. I think the issue is not restriction, but somehow using a dynamic prepared statement inside sp makes my driver think that its returning a resultset, when its clearly not.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't know much about Ruby drivers. A quick google found other issues with ruby driver mysql2 but they all dealt with returning result sets. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902775/error-while-invoking-mysql-stored-procedurethat-returns-resultset-from-rails-3 mentions not using mysql2 driver, and http://nasir.wordpress.com/2007/12/03/stored-procedures-and-rails/ also has you using the ActiveRecord. Perhaps ruby's mysql2 driver assumes all SPs return result. Does a simple SP call work with the driver (without SPs)?